# Is it "she's a vegetarian" or "she's vegetarian"?

Tags: articles

When should I not use indefinite articles? I get very confused.

Comment: I consider both of those options acceptable for *vegetarian*.

Comment: "She is vegetarian" uses *vegetarian* as an **adjective.** Articles can only be applied to nouns. In "She is a vegetarian", *vegetarian* is a noun and can take an article. The same applies to "He is [an] Italian". I've added an answer to our canonical question: thank you for raising the distinction.